# UV Editing: copy UV from one side of a mesh and paste on the other side

Tags: uv

I've got a CUBE with some subdivisions and so on (it's an house).

I did some UV editing to one side of the house and I want to copy that "UV" to the other side of the cube, that has the same geometry.

Is there an automatic way to do it?

thanks